# disable volume option in sound settings android

Tags: android, volume, audio

Is it possible to disable the volume in sound settings? I have googled but could not found satisfied result.

I know there are some apps in Android Market which disable and enable the volume by just pressing the icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the [AudioManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) and try either of this

```
AudioManager volumeControl = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
volumeControl.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

OR

```
AudioManager volumeControl = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
volumeControl.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

Comment: I see that this has been marked as the correct answer, but I don't agree.  I don't believe that this technique will allow you to do what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

There are four kind of sound setting in android 1)Alarm 2)Music 3)Ring Tone 4)Notification
First Create object of AudioManager amanager;
IF you want to set Volume use this code

For Notification

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Alerm

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Music

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Ring Tone

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable changing the volume:

Not possible. Those apps create a Service that constantly monitors the volume and reset it back to what it was once you change it.

If you want to change the volume:
[AudioManager.adjustVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustVolume%28int,%20int%29)

To turn volume on/off:
[AudioManager.setStreamMute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute%28int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: yes i know they create a Service. but how does the enable and disable the volume in that service?

Comment: what do you mean with enable disable volume? Do you want lower the volume to zero or do you want to prevent that people can change the volume?

Comment: Then have a look at @ladiesMan217 2nd answer and replace `STREAM_MUSIC` with `STREAM_RING`

Comment: Thanks Zapl +1 for guiding me.